# CheckboxList on deselect remove the item from Bulleted list

Tags: c#, asp.net, list, for-loop, checkbox

Hi I have this piece of code where I map the selected values of my check boxes to a Bulleted list so far it work ok when I select the value - it maps to bulleted list accordingly. However, I am struggling a bit when users deselects the value. I would like it to update the bulledted list accordingly. Any help?

Here is the code:

```
 public List<string> elements = new List<string>();


protected void checkList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        { foreach(ListItem item in checkList.Items)
            {
                if (item.Selected)
                {
                     elements.Add(item.Text);
                }
                else {//Should this else triger the deletion of the elements in the list? 
                }

            }
            foreach (object o in elements)
            {   int exists = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < BullList.Items.Count; i++)
                {

                    if(BullList.Items[i].ToString() == o.ToString())
                    {
                        exists++;
                    }
                }
                if(exists == 0)
                {
                    BullList.Items.Add(o.ToString());
                }}}

        protected void checkList_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < BullList.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                foreach (ListItem item in checkList.Items)
                {
                    if (BullList.Items[i].ToString() == item.ToString())
                    {
                        item.Selected = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }}}}
```

The DOM elements:

```
  <asp:DropDownList AutoPostBack="true" ID="DropDownJobs" runat="server" Width="390px" Height="42px" Font-Names="Roboto" Font-Size="25px" DataSourceID="jobsDrop" DataTextField="MainJob" DataValueField="IDKey"></asp:DropDownList>       

           <asp:CheckBoxList OnDataBound="checkList_DataBound" AutoPostBack="true" ID="checkList" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="checkList_SelectedIndexChanged" DataSourceID="SortedListJobs" DataTextField="SubJobFamily" DataValueField="SubJobFamily" Width="406px">
            <asp:ListItem>
            </asp:ListItem>  
            </asp:CheckBoxList>

            <h6 class="List">These jobs have been selected:</h6>
            <asp:BulletedList runat="server" ID="BullList" CssClass="bullList"></asp:BulletedList/>
```

Comment: What does the code do now? What do you want it to do instead?

Comment: it adds the selected checkbox item into the bulletedlist I would like it to remove it as well once deselected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you are adding item to `BulletedList` create a `list` of `deselect item`. And then remove it from `BulletedList`. Like below

```
 public List<string> elements = new List<string>();
 public List<string> deselect = new List<string>();


    protected void checkList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    { foreach(ListItem item in checkList.Items)
        {
            if (item.Selected)
            {
                 elements.Add(item.Text);
            }
            else 
            {
             deselect.Add(item.Text);
            }

        }
        foreach (object o in elements)
        {   int exists = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < BullList.Items.Count; i++)
            {

                if(BullList.Items[i].ToString() == o.ToString())
                {
                    exists++;
                }
            }
            if(exists == 0)
            {
                BullList.Items.Add(o.ToString());
            }
         }
      foreach (object o in deselect)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < BullList.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                BullList.Items.Remove(o.ToString());
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: This solution works however getting weird behaviour: when the last item in the list is about to be removed the checkbox event is just ignored... any idea why?

Comment: then once selected a new insert value it just replaces the one that had to be removed in the previous action

Comment: @whiterabbitj your first comment sorry i could not reproduce your problem...second comment i could not understand your question...please explain more... I just answer what you asked in the question...your whole page have lot of controls and lots of code...other code may affect your checkbox and bulleted list. Also where you bind your checkboxlist that may affect the behavior...always bind your control in `page_load` inside `If (!Ispostback)` condition

Comment: ok cheers. Nah I try to remove an item and if it is the last item in the list it stay there. Unless you tick the box of some other item  then that value is just replaced with the selected one.